# NHibernate Linq Like Query Question

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate

Is there any way to make NHibernate.Linq generate a like query on an integer field?  The SQL that I want it to generate is:

```
select IntegerColumn 
from Table 
where IntegerColumn like '%StringValue%'
```

I've tried something like:

```
from entity in _session.Linq<Entity>
where entity.IntegerColumn.ToString().Contains(StringValue)
select entiry.IntegerColumn
```

This produces an ArgumentOutOfRange exception when it evaluates the query.

Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this thread on nhusers](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/22435c89165a1333/f7fb3e94643d5d14)